# Avoid intermediate scrolling positions

Tags: jquery, html, css, web

I'm wondering if there is a library or jQuery plugin to achieve this effect. I want to limit the scrolling to certain positions as done in this site: [Cappen](https://www.cappen.com/works/)

So the idea is to forbid intermediate scrolling. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several Jquery Plugins that you can use to render the same effect of snap scrolling:

[fullPage](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/#firstPage)

[Scrollify](https://projects.lukehaas.me/scrollify/#home)

[panelSnap](http://guidobouman.github.io/jquery-panelsnap/)

Comment: Glad to help. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The site you link is making use of the most popular library for that kind of effect: [fullPage.js](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/).

It is also making use of [its callbacks](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#callbacks) or [state classes](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#state-classes-added-by-fullpagejs) to create the fadeIn and fadeOut animations on its texts.